# pointer to an array created from another struct (not sure if tha'ts correctly worded)C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a problem trying to retrieve info from 2 structs.
The first is:

```
struct PhoneCall{
    std::string date;       
    int minutes;            
    int seconds;
```

the second is :

```
struct Bill{
    Customer holder;                            
    Plan plan;
    PhoneCall callList[BILL_CALL_LIST_SIZE];                                
    int count;                                  
    long durationSeconds;                       
    int block;
```

I have higlighted PhoneCall which has been created from the struct PhoneCall.

I need to solve the function

int GetTotalHours(Bill& bill)

Im finding it difficult to create pointer from bill to Phonecall . I get a message saying no conversion exists.

I have since attempted the following code which was kindly offered as a solution.( I had used something similar but it seems to return an address 001A11EF).

```
int total_hours = 0;

        for (int call = 0; call < BILL_CALL_LIST_SIZE; ++call)
        {
            total_hours += bill.callList[call].minutes / 60+ bill.callList[call].seconds / 3600;
        }
        return total_hours;
```

There is another function later to return total minutes, which is why the function the GetTotalHours is an int type.

I am incredibly new to programming and have jumped in the deep end but hope you can help :)

Comment: I see how your two structs relate to each other, but I still have no clue what you're trying to do or what you mean by "a pointer to two different types"

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Please clarify.

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: Hi @Giorgi  I have edited my question, and hopefully its a little bit clearer for you to understand my question.

Comment: @muppetblues You should not use `int` you should use `double` for `total_hours` because otherwise you will see [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `struct`, if you are given a `Bill` then `GetTotalHours` could be something like

```
double GetTotalHours(Bill const& bill)
{
    double total_hours = 0.0;
    for (int call = 0; call < BILL_CALL_LIST_SIZE; ++call)
    {
        total_hours += bill.callList[call].minutes / 60.0 + bill.callList[call].seconds / 3600.0;
    }
    return total;
}
```

If you have access to C++11, this could be written as

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
double GetTotalHours(Bill const& bill)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(bill.callList),
                           std::end(bill.callList),
                           0.0,
                           [](double total_hours, PhoneCall const& call){ return total_hours + bill.callList[call].minutes / 60.0 + bill.callList[call].seconds / 3600.0; });
}
```

Comment: My apologies will the poor questioning. Please let me Clarify. The main aim of the program is to get the two cheapest phone bill plans. There are 2 more structs but for simplicity,I have left them out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i did try something similar, and i also tried your code but all I got was 001A11EF. Looks Like an address. is there something missing?